# Does Rust/Cargo link statically to MSVCRT?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, compiler-options

In Windows, when compiling C++, I can specify [`/MT` compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library) to use a static version of the runtime library, ie. to **not** link dynamically to MSVCRT.

How does Rust/Cargo behave in this regard, since there is no such option? Does it link static or dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify it I think. Here is the RFC that enabled it:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1721-crt-static.md

There is a page that mentions it in the [rustc book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html?highlight=%2Bcrt-static#target-feature).

> This also supports the feature +crt-static and -crt-static to control static C runtime linkage.

Make a file called `.cargo/config.toml` and inside it you can specify the `rustflags`

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Inside `config.toml`

```
...

[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
...
```

I have not tried this yet though but I imagine it should work.

Comment: Do you have an example of how such option can be added to Cargo.toml?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in the `Cargo.toml` but you can set the environmental variable for it `export CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE=crt-static` or at least that is what the RFC says.

Comment: or another example from the RFC: `RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`

Comment: I edited the answer so you can specify the rustflags in config.toml instead of environmental variables.

Comment: I'm getting `error: unknown codegen option: target-feature`, no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I ended up passing the linker flag in the command line: `RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`. Thank you.